# Model is returning an Instance

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a model like this.

```
class Restaurant {
  final String name;
  final String description;

  const Restaurant(
      {
      this.name,
      this.description});
}
```

when i try to use it it is returning an instance of it. like

```
 print(Restaurant(
          name: 'Hotel 1',
          description: 'Hotel 1'),
    ));
```

it will print 'Instance of Restaurant'. but i was expecting the object

Comment: It is the string representation of the Class you have made.

Comment: so how can i access the whole object instead of the String representaion?

Comment: You need in create a Restaurant instance to be able to acces **name & description**.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche how can i do that please?

Comment: @user10762713 Restaurant restaurantInstance = Restaurant (name: Hotel 1', description: 'Hotel 1');   and use **restaurantInstance**  to access methods and properties. Like : print(restaurantInstance.name);

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `toString` method to your class. The `print` function will invoke it to get the string representation of the object. Example:

```dart
class Restaurant {
  final String name;
  final String description;

  const Restaurant({this.name, this.description});

  String toString() => 'name: $name\ndescription: $description';
}
```